# Actionscript On Mouse Click

Tags: flash, actionscript, click, onmouseclick

Simple question. I have a movieclip. I have an onrollover event for it:

```
this.mc.onRollOver = function() {

}
```

Whats the equivelent for a mouse click event? I tried onMouseClick but it didnt work. I havent used flash in a long time and im a little lost :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either button.onRelease or button.onPress

Comment: onRelease was what I needed. Thanks